# trouble with opening file for read with fopen

Tags: c, linux, fopen

I am new to writing c under linux so this will be maybe silly question, but I have problem using fopen. When I encountered the problem I just tried it with this really simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *test;

   if( fopen("test.txt","r") == NULL )
       printf("didnt open");
   else
       printf("opened!");

   fclose(test); 
}
```

test.txt is in same folder as this code and a.out. When I debug a.out I get:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at testit.c:14
14      if( fopen("test.txt","r") == NULL )
(gdb) s
_IO_new_fopen (filename=0x400696 "test.txt", mode=0x400694 "r") at iofopen.c:103
103   iofopen.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) s
__fopen_internal (filename=0x400696 "test.txt", mode=0x400694 "r", is32=1) at iofopen.c:65
65  in iofopen.c
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_IO_new_fclose (fp=0x0) at iofclose.c:54
54  iofclose.c: No such file or directory.
```

I tried changing the path: `if( fopen("/home/h1657/Work/test/test.txt","r") == NULL )`. Had the same effect.

I am sorry if this is basic question but I can't find any solution to this.

Comment: `FILE *test;` where you used then why `fclose(test);`? It should be `if((test = fopen("test.txt","r")) == NULL )` and and most important thing: is `test.txt` is present in current directory from where you execute your program?

Comment: is that `testtest.txt` full path a typo in your code or typo here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many issues in posted code:

- You haven't assign/initialize the file pointer `FILE *test;`. So it
  will point to nothing/garbage value. Now closing that using `fclose`
  cause undefined behaviour.may be crash your program.

  So the code should be

> ```
>    FILE *test;
>    test = fopen("test.txt","r");
>    //close file pointer(after process on file) if fopen success.
> ```

- confirm first what is your file name.if it's `testtest.txt` OR
  `test.txt` OR `test.txt.txt`(in windows it will occur if you manually
  give `.txt` extension and hide the extension ). Need to confirm it
  first then according it give name in code.
- You have `int main`.So you should have `return 0` at the end of the
  main.

Comment: So should I rather post new question ?

Comment: Ok, thank you for advice and for correct answer as well.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding `gdb`'s message:

```
iofopen.c: No such file or directory.
```

You would get that message from `gdb` anyway, even if your code was correct. That is because you are using `step` instead of `next`.

Full explanation is below:

> "The step command follows the code into a function call. When
>   stepping, gdb prints each source line before executing it. If you step
>   into a library function, gdb wants to display the source, but those
>   file are not available on the system. The complaint is expected and
>   harmless. If you use the next command instead, it will step over and
>   treat the entire call as a single step."

from http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs107/guide_gdb.html

In fact, try to `gdb` again the correct code with `step` and you will get the same message `iofopen.c: No such file or directory.`

Answer (score 3):

Your don't store the result of fopen into test. The segfault is normal, and the code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *test = fopen("test.txt","r");

   if( test == NULL )
       printf("didnt open");
   else {
       printf("opened!");
       fclose(test); 
   }
}
```

As for the fopen failing:

```
fopen("/home/h1657/Work/testtest.txt", "r")
```

If you tried that, then the filename is not `test.txt`, or you are missing a `/`.

You should:

- check file permissions. Can you read the file ?
- check the path; in the console where you are executing the file, simply do `stat file.txt`. If that fails, the result will be: *stat: cannot stat `file.txt': No such file or directory*

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the return value of fopen to your FILE pointer. Otherwise, your FILE pointer will point to an arbitrary address (it's initial value, which is most likely garbage). When fclose is dereferencing this pointer, it will fail.

Also, make sure to exit the programm when opening the file fails.